# Transform boundingBox according to angle and rotation

Tags: swift, machine-learning, bounding-box, mlmodel, visionkit

I am trying to implement a plastic cards detector using Vision ML Model which was trained on a custom data set. I am drawing rectangles according to bounding boxes coordinates over the camera view and it works like a charm. BUT. It doesn't react to changes in the angle, or rotation. You can see this on the screens below.

[image: 2022-12-04-03-28-28.jpg]
[image: 2022-12-04-03-28-33.jpg]

The ideal solution already exists in the same Vision library, but for rectangles detection. It has `topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight` with which I can draw whatever quadrilateral, but object detection has only bounding box property which actually is `CGRect` (ML model really required here for future changes).
I found a lot of similar answers, but they had different contexts or language or the task itself.

Maybe there is some way to do it with `CGAffineTransform` or configure model training better? Thanks!

Comment: If my answer didn’t satisfy you maybe you could add a bit more details about what you want?

Comment: Detecting rectangles inside the detected object is quite tricky and unstable. I want to receive 4 points from observation (not a rectangle) and draw a perfect border with these points around my credit card

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the object you need using object detector model and then use `VNDetectRectanglesRequest`. It may be a little bit slow, but this way you don't have to train anything :)